# Add/Delete Items from DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add or delete items from my DataContext? This is my code:

```
class WallModel
{
    public WallModel()
    {
        WallItems = new ObservableCollection<Wall>();
        Initialization = InitializeAsync();

    }
    public Task Initialization { get; private set; }
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
            WallItems.Add(new Wall { id = 2, user = 3 });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Wall> WallItems { get; set; }
}
```

And MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new WallModel();
    lvMain.DataContext = DataContext;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where do you want to add/delete items to?

Comment: I believe you could just type `((WallModel)lvMain.DataContext).WallItems.Remove(..)`, but you must have meant something else.

Comment: Further to my comments below, learning to use the MVVM pattern will boost your WPF based productivity massively http://mvvmbasics.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2):

We *don't* generally add or remove items from a `DataContext` directly. Instead, (in MVVM) we try to create a class that incorporates all of the properties that we want to display in the UI and methods that perform the required functionality. Then we set an instance of this class as the `DataContext`.

Of course, you *can* just set a simple collection property as the `DataContext` of one control and in that case, you could just add or remove items from that collection as normal. However, it is generally preferred to manipulate the data item(s) set as the `DataContext` rather than the `DataContext` object itself.

Comment: OP didn't specify MVVM but it is correct to recommend it to him/her for WPF work. MVVM is an excellent fit for WPF. there are at least 2 non-mvvm methods for achieving this goal but MVVM is always less code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example:

```
((WallModel)DataContext).WallItems.Remove(item);
```

or

```
((WallModel)DataContext).WallItems.RemoveAt(index);
```

....

Also if lvMain is in the MainPage you do not need to set its datacontext because it gets inherited.

As Sheridan mentions use a viewmodel and a Delete command which removes the item directly in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

((WallModel)DataContext).WallItems.Add(new Wall { id = 2, user = 3 });